# clearing canvas just before setInterval repeats

Tags: javascript

So here's the code:

```
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var RectCount = 0;
ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
setInterval(function () {
    for (RectCount = 0; RectCount < 2000; RectCount += 1) {
        var x = 2000 * Math.random(),
            y = 2000 * Math.random();
        ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, 1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
}, 1000);
setInterval(function () {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
}, 999);
```

This works fine however over time the fact that it clears the canvas every 999 milliseconds becomes evident after a short while. Is there any way to contain the `clearRect` within the previous `setInterval` function and still keep it working as is?

Comment: Why don't you clear the canvas before entering the `for` loop?

Comment: thanks, worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this effect by using [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead of the two `setInterval()` functions you have here - which obvious slip out of phase over time.

The basic principle goes like this...

```
/* window.requestAnimationFrame
   simple cross-browser with fallback */
var RAF = (function(callback) {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
}());

// drawing function
function loop() {
    /* clear canvas or fillRect entire area */
    /* paint new stuff to canvas */
    RAF(loop);
}

// call drawing function for first time
loop();
```

The loop function now calls itself over-and-over round-and-round.  As `RAF()` is just a timing function that synchronises with the screen refresh rate add the [`window.setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) method to the loop to control timing, like so...

```
var time = 999;

function loop() {
    /* clear canvas or fillRect entire area */
    /* paint new stuff to canvas */
    setTimeout(function() {
        RAF(loop);
    }, time);
}
```

Here, the `loop()` function will call itself every 999 milliseconds plus however long it takes a device to process the canvas image.

Hope that helped :)